# is there a basic law to minimize round-off error

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

Given any formula, what is the principle to organize the computations to make the round-off error as small as possible? Is there a good book talk about this?

For example.
$$
f(x)*g(y)*z(t)
$$
, where $x,y,t$ are varaibles. and $f,g,z$ can be any functions.

For a better round-off error, is there a basic law to determine to compute (f*g) first or (g*z) first?

Comment: Most texts on numerical analysis will discuss this, some more than others.  Generally multiplication does not have a preferred order to avoid roundoff, but may have one to avoid overflow.  Addition and subtraction are the ones that have roundoff problems because you can be subtracting nearly equal things.

Comment: Would you mind recommending one?